# Adding ImageView beside the textView in the same line

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I have a TextView and an ImageView in a CardView.
I have one problem with the TextView.
When the TextView text is longer than CardView length, it shows against the ImageView and I don't want that.

Like this picture:

[image]

I want it so that when the text touches the ImageIiew, it shows `...` for indicating the text continuation.

> row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_file_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_red_500_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the screen shot of what I want :

[image]

Comment: try to add the drawableleft (put drawable image ) and put padding drawablepadding with your Textview

Comment: show screenshot what you want.

Comment: @Ironman i add screenshot from my goal .

Answer (score 3):

Try This following code. Hope it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_file_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_red_500_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This is tested. How it doesnt work :O . output of my end http://imgur.com/BcvwVFr

Comment: my mean is not suitable for me !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting an ImageView and a TextView in a RelativeLayout, you can take advantage of **compound drawable**.
Meaning that you can add drawables **inside** the TextView, rather than outside of it.

I.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_file_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_red_500_24dp"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is also faster, because you get rid of a ViewGroup and a View at once (the less you use, the faster)

Optionally, you can also set a margin between the compound drawables and the text, by using the `android:drawablePadding` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:src ="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_red_500_24dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_file_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="bjbjgbdgkgbndbndkbdkb..fg.bgbfgnbnfgb."
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

your output look like this which you want.

[image]